# I am trying to create space invaders using kaboom js in replit ide Err

Tags: javascript, replit, kaboom

I'm trying to change the scene to lose state when player runs out of time or aliens invades successfully but I'm getting this error

Error: scene not found : lose

Since I cannot put everything here ,I'm putting my replit link over here

https://replit.com/@shubhambarve/ConcernedDarkorchidTypes#code/main.js

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to make a scene for lose

```
   scene("lose", () => {
    add([
    text(args.score),
    ])
   })
```